# Integrating the incomplete Gamma function $\Gamma(b,x) d \Gamma(a,x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Can any one please show me why

$\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-sx} \Gamma(b,x) dx = \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{a(1+s)^{a+b}}F(1,a+b; 1+a ; s/(1+s))$,

where $F(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function, as given in [eq. 8.14.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.14).

Why the equality holds ? 
Are there any insightful bounds to this expression ?

Any clues on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\text{Re}(s)>0$, let we start with:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(a,b,s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{a-1}e^{-sx}\Gamma(b,x)\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{x}^{+\infty} x^{a-1} e^{-sx} y^{b-1} e^{-y}\,dy\,dx\\&=& \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{a-1} e^{-(s+1)x} (y+x)^{b-1} e^{-y}\,dy\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
and perform the change of variable $x=x,\,(s+1)x+y=z$ to get:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(a,b,s)&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{(s+1)x}^{+\infty} x^{a-1} (z-sx)^{b-1} e^{-z}\,dz \,dx\\&=&(s+1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{x}^{+\infty} x^{a-1} ((s+1)u-sx)^{b-1} e^{-(s+1)u}\,du \,dx\\&=&(s+1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{1}^{+\infty} x^{a+b-1} ((s+1)t-s)^{b-1} e^{-(s+1)xt}\,dt \,dx\\&=&\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{(s+1)^{a}}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\left(t-\frac{s}{s+1}\right)^{b-1} t^{-a-b}\,dt \\&=&\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{(s+1)^{a}}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{s}{s+1}\right)^{b-1} r^{a+b-2}\,dr 
\\&=&\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{(s+1)^{a}}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-\frac{s}{s+1}r\right)^{b-1} r^{a-1}\,dr.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now the claim follows from:
$$\phantom{}_2 F_1(a,b;c;\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}\int_{0}^{1}r^{b-1}(1-r)^{c-b-1}(1-r\beta)^{-a}\,dr. $$

Comment: @sefi: you're welcome.

Comment: Hi @Jack D'Aurizio, could you please tell me why the first variable in the hypergeometric function is $1$ according to the reference? It seems like it should be $b-1$ according to this representation.